# .net mvc 5 unobtrusive disable field validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc, validation

this is a short answer. does anyone know how to disable a field validation on javascript using .net mvc unobtrusive validation?. I have a view model field with `[Require]` Datannotation but depending user's decision could be a required or not in the view, i would manage view model validation on my controller using `modelState.remove("field")`.

i appreciate your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to amend the rules based on the user's decision. When the field is no longer required, do the following:

```js
$('#Property').rules('remove', 'required')
```

You can wrap this in a listener on the `#OtherProperty`:

```js
$('#OtherProperty').change(function(e) {

  if (someCondition) {
    $('#Property').rules('remove', 'required')
  } else {
    $('#Property').rules('add', 'required')
  }

});
```

Comment: @jumpingcode I get a wierd issue. Im also disabling the 'Property' field and if i run this on multiple fields i get an error in jquery validate that settings is null. Have you run across this using the rules approach?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the dataannotation just adds the HTML [required](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_required.asp) attribute. This gets added when you use the HTML helpers such as `@Html.TextboxFor`. I believe it checks this attribute with the unobtrusive  validation library.

Using javascript or jquery you should be able to dynamically remove or add this attribute.

Example - Removing required attribute in jQuery

```
$('#MyInput').removeAttr('required');
```

**Update**

It doesn't add the required attribute it adds data-rule-required="true"

Just remove this attribute. It it still doesn't update you might need to reinitialise the validation code.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I added an update as it may be adding the data-rule-required attribute. Unfortunately I cannot test this myself directly as I'm away from a computer.

Comment: I believe it adds `data-val-required`, amongst other things

Comment: i forgot to say i tried that way. unobtrusive generates the following attributes on the input field: data-val="true" data-val-required="true" i wrote $('#MyInput').removeAttr('data-val'); and $('#MyInput').removeAttr('data-val-required'); and still not working

Comment: I think the validator applies listeners so you might need to reinitialise the validation on that form. I don't know the code off the top of my head unfortunately